# Wireless Repeater/Access network design

Tags: networking, wifi

So I have a need to setup a access point / Repeater, if that's the correct term.  What I really need is to have a switch that is in another location to receive its connection to the network via wireless and still allow the use of the 10/100 ports.

[Here is a diagram](https://imgur.com/aY4TA) of what I want to do; the device i need is in red.

I'm not sure what type of hardware can do this type of task.  Are there any broad suggestions on what sort of equipment I need?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could achieve this with the Linksys WRT54GL and a custom firmware, such as Tomato, DD-WRT or OpenWRT. I have a similar setup, but just haven't purchased the 2nd AP yet .... my plan was to purchase a 2nd WRT54GL though.

Here is a guide on setting up a client bridge for DD-WRT:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

Comment: Even the diagrams are the same http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Image:Repeater_Bridge.jpg :)

Comment: i have an older wrt sitting around and was thinking that DDWRT would work.  thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there is a supported N version of this router?

Comment: I don't know if there's a N version available. This link will show you a list of 802.11n devices that DD-WRT supports though: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices_802.11n

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the UK, but I'm sure you could get something similar to this: [Tenda Wireless-N150 Access Point](http://www.ebuyer.com/product/169923) fairly cheaply in the US. If you look at the reviews for that product, someone gives a very detailed description of how to set this up as an Access Point/LAN Bridge- which I think is what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

- [Bridging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29) is one way to achieve it
- Straight [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)#Bridging_versus_routing) giving your red segment clients default route that goes to existing router will make things work
- You could even do [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) from red segment to black and have your network work, but it is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

[Linksys WPGS606](http://www.netgear.co.uk/wireless_print_server_wgps606.php). It's classed as a 'wireless print server', but it has a built in wireless bridge, a 4-port switch and 2 USB ports for printers. I used one a year or so ago to link a Sony PS2, a VoIP phone and printer to a home network. I can also confirm that Trevor's suggestion of a client bridge using dd-wrt will work - I've done that too with an Asus WL-500g premium router.